# Candidate Strategy for GenericUserBasedRecommender in Mahout

Tags: mahout, recommendation-engine

In mahout you can define a `CandidateItemsStrategy` for `GenericItemBasedRecommender` such that specific items e.g. of a certain category are excluded.
When using a `GenericUserBasedRecommender` this is not possible. How can I accomplish this with `GenericUserBasedRecommender`? Is the only way to do this using a `IDRescorer`? If possible I'd like to avoid using a `IDRescorer`. Thank you for your help!

[Edit]

For the item based recommender I do it like this:

```
private final class OnlySpecificlItemsStrategy implements CandidateItemsStrategy {
    private final JpaDataModel dataModel;

    public OnlySpecificlItemsStrategy(JpaDataModel dataModel) {
        this.dataModel = dataModel;
    }

    @Override
    public FastIDSet getCandidateItems(long userID, PreferenceArray preferencesFromUser, DataModel dataModel) throws TasteException {
        List<Long> specificlItemIDs  = this.dataModel.getSpecificlItemIDs();
        FastIDSet candidateItemIDs = new FastIDSet();

        for (long itemID : specificlItemIDs)
          candidateItemIDs.add(itemID);

        for (int j = 0; j < preferencesFromUser.length(); j++)
            candidateItemIDs.remove(preferencesFromUser.getItemID(j));

        return candidateItemIDs;
    }

}
```

For the user based recommender I do it with a Rescorer:

```
public class FilterIDsRescorer implements IDRescorer {

    FastIDSet allowedIDs;

    public FilterIDsRescorer(FastIDSet allowedIDs) {
        this.allowedIDs = allowedIDs;
    }

    @Override
    public double rescore(long id, double originalScore) {
        return originalScore;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isFiltered(long id) {
        return !this.allowedIDs.contains(id);
    }

}
```

and then set it up like this:

```
List<Long> specificItemIDsList = dataModel.getOtherSpecificlItemIDs();
FastIDSet specificItemIDs = new FastIDSet(specificItemIDsList.size());
for (Long id : specificItemIDsList) {
    specificItemIDs.add(id);
}
this.filterIDsRescorer = new FilterIDsRescorer(specificItemIDs );
userBasedRecommender.recommend(userID, howMany, this.filterIDsRescorer)
```

For the purpose of filtering/excluding certain items I could also subclass my data model for each type of recommender, but then I cannot share the same data model instance which would have an impact on performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a way to do this. The user-based and item-based algorithms are not quite symmetric, and it's mostly on purpose. The user-based system already has a notion of user neighborhood which is kind of like this idea. `IDRescorer` is unrelated.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Sean. Maybe my question was not clear enough. I edited my question such that you can see how I do it at the moment. I'd like to know whether this is the way to go or whether there is a more efficient and elegant solution. Another solution could be subclassing my data model and only return the "specific" items instead of all items. What do you think?

Comment: Ah if this is what you want to do then you want IDRescorer yes. It works for all recommenders. Your CandidateItenStrategy version is really an optimization for item based and should also work.