# Excluding certain ratings when running recommender

Tags: mahout, recommendation-engine

This relates to [Candidate Strategy for GenericUserBasedRecommender in Mahout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8773861/candidate-strategy-for-genericuserbasedrecommender-in-mahout)

I have database with items rated based on numeric values: 1,2,3,4

However, when running the recommender I would, in some cases, want to
exclude items with rating 4.

I considered IDRescorer but reckon that it only filters items after the
recommender has already recommended. I would like items filtered
before recommendations i.e. they should not be included when calculating
recommendations.

On other hand CandidateItemsStrategy would be ideal but only works for GenericItemBasedRecommender. I am using GenericUserBasedRecommender.

What's the best way of handling this in mahout?

Answer (score 0):

Answered this on the mailing list: `IDRescorer` *does* filter before computing the initial score. However, if your logic is "exclude items scored 4" of course that must happen after scoring and you can't use `isFiltered()`. But you can return `NaN` from `rescore()` to filter after that. Of course you could not avoid scoring for this logic! But `isFiltered()` could avoid scoring if the logic was anything not dependent on the score.

`CandidateItemsStrategy` is not relevant.